# Disable excel error alerts in Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open 

Tags: .net, office-interop

Using Interop to render a number of Excel files to XPS.   Many .Open fail with error message VBA requires a component that is not currently installed.  If I click OK it continues.  Can I configure it to skip VBA?   Using Office 2010 64bit on Windows 2008 Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

you can set this property of Application Object and it won't show excel errors. But I'd suggest to fix the installation error if your program is going to call VBA code or macro.

Comment: Thanks. I am testing out your answer now.  What do you mean by fix installation error? I have Office 2010 x64 with all patches. Disabled macros.  Just need the XPS for 40,000 files.

Comment: If you're not using VBA code and have disabled macros then you don't need to install missing component that VBA is complaining about. you should be good :)